# Indexing using Database Engine tuning advisor

Tags: sql-server, performance

We got a requirement to index a database. We planned to use db engine tuning advisor to get index recommendations. When we analyse the script using database tuning advisor we got both index recommendations and statics recommendations.

Whether we have to consider both index recommendations and statics recommendations to get the tabled indexed? Or what actually the statistics recommendations meant?

Mahesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "consider" both the index and statistical recommendations.

What you should look to do is evaluate the changes that are being proposed to understand why they are being recommended to you. Then using your judgement, test the changes which you have identified as being plausible, on a non production server.

Are you using the DTA to analyse a single T-SQL Script or are you running a representative workload though?

If you are looking at just single script consider that the tuning recommendations are isolated to just the specific case you are looking at and you cannot factor in how other queries will be affected by the proposed changes.

Comment: I am using a single query as workload and then analyse it. Which is the best practice using separate queries as workload or use all queries in a single workload file?

Comment: @mahesh: Well it depends. It's perfectly acceptable to tune a query in isolation so long as you factor that into your design decisions. When performing database wide Index Tuning, the preference is to run the DTA using a representative trace of your production workload.